# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable appears 2/3 of the time

Tags: python, pyautogui

I am coding a bot to click a certain image when it sees another image. I am not only getting the error above, but when one picture is shown, it will click the opposite picture's corresponding picture.

```py
import pyautogui
import time

pyautogui.screenshot('test.png')


xy1 = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('Rubberq.png', confidence=0.4)
if xy1 == None:
    print('Skip Rubber')
else:
    RubberA = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('RubberA.png')
    RubberAPoint = pyautogui.center(RubberA)
    Rubberx, Rubbery = RubberAPoint
    pyautogui.click(Rubberx, Rubbery)


xy2 = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('DutchQ.png', confidence=0.4)
if xy2 == None:
    print('Skip Dutch')
else:
    DutchA = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('DutchA.png')
    DutchAPoint = pyautogui.center(DutchA)
    Dutchx, Dutchy = DutchAPoint
    pyautogui.click(Dutchx, Dutchy)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Python\Quizlet_Hack.py\QuizletV1.py", line 11, in <module>
    RubberAPoint = pyautogui.center(RubberA)
  File "C:\Users\evanf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 581, in center
    return Point(coords[0] + int(coords[2] / 2), coords[1] + int(coords[3] / 2))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: please paste the stacktrace.

Comment: @LeiYang Just posted it

Comment: seems `DutchA = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('DutchA.png')` isn't always sucessful. you may want `print(DutchA)` and do some check before `pyautogui.center`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using path:

```
import pyautogui
import time

pyautogui.screenshot('test.png')


xy1 = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('\\...\\Rubberq.png', confidence=0.4) #Paste image path
if xy1 == None:
    print('Skip Rubber')
else:
    RubberA = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('\\...\\RubberA.png') #Paste image path
    time.sleep(5) #Allow py read pixels
    RubberAPoint = pyautogui.center(RubberA)
    Rubberx, Rubbery = RubberAPoint
    pyautogui.click(Rubberx, Rubbery)


xy2 = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('\\...\\DutchQ.png', confidence=0.4) #Paste image path
if xy2 == None:
    print('Skip Dutch')
else:
    time.sleep(5) #Allow py read pixels
    DutchA = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('\\...\\DutchA.png') #Paste image path
    DutchAPoint = pyautogui.center(DutchA)
    Dutchx, Dutchy = DutchAPoint
    pyautogui.click(Dutchx, Dutchy)
```

If it doesn't work, try increase degree of confidence `confidence=0.9`